# Ask for SQL Server database restore after automatic scheduler backup by batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2012, database-restore

If I am doing SQL Server database backup by these links:
[Executing a SQL Server Script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817092/executing-a-sql-server-script-from-a-batch-file)
and  [Executing a SQL Server Script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817092/executing-a-sql-server-script-from-a-batch-file)

How do I restore database back if necessary?

Comment: Just create 2nd .sql file with RESTORE DATABASE... command, and run it exactly as you do for backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bat files for back up and restore databases here is a link [Automate Sql Server Database backup & Restore Using Sqlcmd](http://www.codeplussoft.com/Pages/sqlautobackuprestore) which will help you